# Time Difference PHP

Tags: php, time, difference

I'm trying to build a skill tracker that displays how long a user has worked on learning a particular skill. As a result, I have a while loop that loops through everything in my database but I'm stuck on how to get the difference between two times for each iteration through the loop. They are formatted as H:m:s in 12 hour time (e.g. 09:05:00).

For example, let's say I worked on two skills for the date of 7/2/15. The result should look like the following:

```
| Skill Name | Time Started | Time Finished | Difference |
| ---------- | ------------ | ------------- | ---------- |
| Bootstrap  | 9:05:00 AM   | 11:15:00 AM   |  2:10:00   |
| CSS        | 10:50:00 PM  | 11:50:00 PM   |  1:00:00   |
| Python     | 10:00:00 AM  | 1:00:00 PM    |  3:00:00   |
```

Here's my code (excuse the deprecated statements. This will only be used by me):

```
     $skilltoview = $_POST['skilltoview'];

        include("db.php");

        //retrieve data from database
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM timer WHERE skillname='$skilltoview'");


        echo "<div class='table-responsive'>";
        echo "<table class='table table-striped table-bordered'>";
        echo "<thead>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>ID</th><th>Skill Name</th><th>Skill Date</th><th>Time Started</th><th>Time Ended</th><th>Notes</th><th>Difference</th>";
        echo "</tr></thead>";
        echo "<tbody>"; 

        function timeDifference($timeEnd, $timeStart){
        $tResult = strtotime($timeEnd) - strtotime($timeStart);
        return date("G:i", $tResult);
        }


    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $id = $row['id'];
        $start = $row['timestarted'];
        $stop = $row['timestopped'];

        echo "
        <tr>
            <td>$id</td>
            <td>$row[skillname]</td>
            <td>$row[date]</td>
            <td>$row[timestarted]</td>
            <td>$row[timestopped]</td>
            <td>$row[notes]</td>
            <td>"; print(timeDifference($start, $stop)); echo "</td>
            <td><a href ='edittracker.php?id=$id'>Edit</a>
            <td><a onClick='deleteConfirm(); return false;' href='#'><center>Delete</center></a></a>
        </tr>";

        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
        function deleteConfirm(){
        var r = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this skill log?');
        if (r == true) {
        window.location='deletetracker.php?id=$id';
        } else {
            x = 'You pressed Cancel!';
        }
        }
        </script>";
    }
        echo "</tbody>"; 
        echo "</table>";
        echo "</div>"; 

        //close connection
        mysql_close($conn);
```

Comment: What is the output that you are getting so we can compare to what you want.

Comment: @Brian Cohan: It's the oddest thing but it returns `0:59` as the difference no matter what time is passed to the function.

Comment: You can make the query compute the time difference for you... e.g. `"SELECT timestarted, timestopped, timestopped-timestarted AS timeelapsed FROM timer WHERE skillname='$skilltoview'"`

Comment: What is the data schema like? how  are timestarted and timestopped stored? Are they timestamp, datetime, varchar?

Comment: @Brian Cohan: timestarted and timestopped are both stored as time.

Comment: @mike.k: Works great, however, the result outputs in seconds. Anyway to change that directly from the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of what's wrong with the php-code, you can make your database-server calculate the difference just as easily; use [TIMEDIFF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) and add that to your query:

```
SELECT *, TIMEDIFF(timestopped, timestarted) as diff FROM timer WHERE skillname='$skilltoview'
```

you can then print `<td>$row[diff]</td>` directly

Comment: @hikaru12 - divide it by 3600

Comment: @Sjon: Like so? `$diffhour = $row['diff']/3600;`

Comment: @Sjon, also having issues when it crosses from AM to PM. For example, if I do `10:00:00 AM` and stopped as `1:30:00 PM` I get the remainder of the day left from 24 hour time `-08:30:00`. Anyway to fix that?

Comment: @hikaru12 if you want to fix that nicely you should consider replacing your time columns with timestamp columns instead; those include a date and will make this easier

Comment: No need to use dates if you only deal with times. [Use field type `TIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/time.html).

Comment: @Glavić that's what he's using; how do you propose to fix http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31186323/time-difference-php/31186919?noredirect=1#comment50381083_31186919 using TIMEs?

Comment: No, he is not using TIME field type, you can see that by string prefix AM and PM.